# Google Sheets formula column auto drag when new data is uploaded

Tags: google-sheets, automation, vlookup

On google sheets, I have a python program that updates 4 columns with 97 rows of data twice a day. In column 5, I have a formula used to track sales but I am forced to manually drag or click the formula to autofill in the new rows of data.

I have tried using the ArrayFormula() function but since I am using Vlookup to search the name of the location in each individual row it is not working since the cell reference is not being dragged down with the formula. Is there another alternative that could be made in order to automatically fill in the extra rows without having to open the google sheet?

Vlookup formula: =IF(B2<VLOOKUP(A2, A3:D194, 2, FALSE), 0, B2-VLOOKUP(A2, A3:D194, 2, FALSE))

Array Formula attempt: =ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B<VLOOKUP(A2:A, A3:D194, 2, FALSE), 0, B2:B-VLOOKUP(A2:A, A3:D194, 2, FALSE)))

The excel data would look like this and would repeat with the names in different locations

| Location Name | Quantity | Date | Time | Daily Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Springville | 38 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |
| Willow Creek | 37 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 4 |
| Pineview | 33 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 3 |
| Lakeside | 30 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |
| Clearwater | 29 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 0 |
| Oakville | 29 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |
| Meadowbrook | 28 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |
| Cedar Ridge | 27 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 0 |
| Maplewood | 27 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 0 |
| Riverdale | 27 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |
| Forest Hills | 26 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 0 |
| Sunnyside | 26 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 0 |
| Greenwood | 26 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |
| Lakeview | 25 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 0 |
| Sunset Heights | 25 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 2 |
| Laurel Hill | 24 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |
| Briarwood | 23 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |
| Oakwood | 22 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |
| Cedar Heights | 21 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 16 |
| Pinecrest | 21 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 0 |
| Mountain View | 21 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 2 |
| Willowbrook | 19 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 0 |
| Maple Valley | 19 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 0 |
| Riverside | 19 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |
| Lakefront | 19 | 27/07/2023 | 19:12 | 1 |

Comment: your formula looks fine to me. What exactly "is not working"?

Comment: The formula is correct but the array formula does not take into account the cell references. When I drag the formula down the cells go from A2 to A3, A4, and so on but using the array formula the way I am does not seem to take that into account leaving me with 0s in all my rows

Comment: am I missing something? The point of using array formula is that you don't have to drag the formula down.

Comment: The array formula is not working correctly then because it only outputs rows equal to 0 which I assume is because of the first reference cell which comes out to 0 in the working equation.

Comment: the formula you have does exactly what you're telling it to do. If that's not the result you're expecting could you explain in words what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am just trying to automatically run that Vlookup function when new data is added in through a python script so I dont have to open google sheets and manually drag down the formula. @ztiaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with array formulas, providing a range to an argument that by default expects a range will not cause it to shift to the next row. Here's what you can try instead:

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(α,b,IF(α="",,LET(vl,VLOOKUP(α,OFFSET(α,1,,9^9,2),2,0),IF(b<vl,0,b-vl)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAP and the LAMBDA function.

```
=MAP(A2:A, B2:B, LAMBDA(a, b, 
  IF(b<VLOOKUP(a,A3:D194,2,FALSE),0,
     b-VLOOKUP(a,A3:D194,2,FALSE))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two values being contemplated row by row you can try with MAP:

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(aval,bval,IF(aval="","",IF(bval<VLOOKUP(aval, A3:D194, 2, FALSE), 0,bval-VLOOKUP(aval, A3:D194, 2, FALSE)))))
```

You can also simplify the IF statement with the help of MAX:

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(aval,bval,IF(aval="","",MAX(0,bval-VLOOKUP(aval, A3:D194, 2, FALSE)))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work and fills the column with only 0's

Comment: Could you share some sample sheet to test and see what could be happening?

Comment: @Jawn what are your expected results or process of thinking? As far as I see in your table, there's only once each value, so the result of the VLOOKUP will be exactly the same as the original value. Hence, it will obviously return 0, because it's substracting by itself